# Which Version of Bluetooth does Android Froyo Support

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wanted to know if Android 2.2 (Froyo) supports Bluetooth V3 . If any of you guys know let me know.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Bluetooth page at the Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/porting/bluetooth.html#androidBluetoothFeatures) Froyo supports "Bluetooth 2.1+EDR host stack".